# Given an Exception instance, print the traceback

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I have an exception instance (a `KeyError` that was raised somewhere deep in the code, to be more precise) and I would like to print the whole traceback and not just the name of the missing key. I am reading the documentation of [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module, but I struggle to see a way. The `dir()` called with the exception instance did not help me either.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: If you *just* caught the exception, you can use `sys.exc_info()` to get the traceback associated with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case - it is hidden somewhere under a bunch of `Promise`s and I struggle to decrypt what is actually going on there.

Comment: I solved it by finding the actual exception and getting the traceback there - the whole afternoon is gone :/. I still wonder if I could have avoided this and get away just with the exception